# In UNIX, the rm='rm -I' is not working

Tags: bash, unix

In the command prompt of g++ terminal, I am typing alias rm='rm -I' and it is giving me missing operand.

I'm not quite sure what I should do, and yes I know naming it rm is bad.  It is for an assignment, and the teacher specifically wants it to be rm, and then it should prompt the user as such.... rm xyz?  because the command before this is touch xyz1 xyz2 xyz3 xyz4.

However, as I said, it is saying missing operand even after I source my aliases and I have tried to fix it with double quotes and single quotes without success.

Comment: Some shell implementations would see this as a recursive definition. You can avoid it by using **alias rm="\`which rm\` -I"** (I had to use bold, since back-quotes do not render properly as code).

Comment: you have not yet shared **what exactly** your shell says, what shell you are using, and and and... this is **not the place to crowd-source your homework**. Read AFH's comment as an invitation to **read** the **man page for your $SHELL**, and also the **man page for rm**. Search for the string "Request confirmation" - it is **-i** for the version of rm I'm using...

Comment: First of all you should check that the argument exists in "rm" by doing "rm --help" or "man rm".

Otherwise, the alias should work simply like that: alias rm='rm ...'. That said, aliasing "safe" executions of otherwise dangerous commands is very dangerous since the programmers get used to expect a warning, thus getting into trouble when this system is not set up for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `alias rm="rm -i"`.

-i as in interactive, not -l as in list; the latter not commonly an `rm` option.  the `-i` flag will prompt for each file deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for is an alias:

```
alias rm='rm -I'
```

By contrast, the command `rm='rm -I'` merely creates a shell variable, named `rm`, that contains the text `rm- I`.